# How to compare a variable containing a date in PHP to current time to figure out time passed

Tags: php, datetime

How can I tell if a variable that contains a stampdate like this “2015-05-12 15:32:53” is less or more than an hour comparing it with current timestamp? Is there any good function in PHP that I can use to compare with this time format?

I have this code:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d h:i:s a', time()); //Current time e.g. "“2015-05-12 13:32:53”
$timetocomp; //Contains “2015-05-12 15:32:53”
```

My question is how I can compare them to know if 2 hours have passed or not.

Comment: timestamp is the keyword here

Comment: Or DateTime objects, which can also be compared directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `DateTime`

```
  $timetocomp = "2015-06-27 09:10:53"; // its 2015-05-28 08:5x:xx now
  $dateTimeToCompare = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timetocomp);
  var_dump($dateTimeToCompare);
  $dateTimeNoW = new DateTime();

  $diff = $dateTimeToCompare->diff($dateTimeNoW);


  if($diff->h >= 1 or $diff->d > 0 or $diff->m > 0 or $diff->y > 0) {
    echo "difference of at least 1 hour";
  } else {
    echo "difference less than 1 hour";
  }
```

Edit: My mistake was that I assumed **$diff** would contain the difference for each size, but its seperated as `var_dump($diff)` showed.

```
object(DateInterval)#3 (15) {
    ["y"]=> int(0)
    ["m"]=> int(0)
    ["d"]=> int(30)
    ["h"]=> int(0)
    ["i"]=> int(15)
    ["s"]=> int(13)
    ["weekday"]=> int(0)
    ["weekday_behavior"]=> int(0)
    ["first_last_day_of"]=> int(0)
    ["invert"]=> int(1)
    ["days"]=> int(30)
    ["special_type"]=> int(0)
    ["special_amount"]=> int(0)
    ["have_weekday_relative"]=> int(0)
    ["have_special_relative"]=> int(0)
  }
```

So I updated the If-clause to also chck the days, months and years.

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct() expects parameter 2 to be DateTimeZone

Comment: Oh yes copied the wrong line. change the first line do `date_create_from_format`, see here http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: It seems like that code only checks for the time but not for the date, I changed the date to be 10 days from now and it still prints out that the difference is less than 1 hour.

Comment: You were right. I assumed **$diff** would contain the difference for all variables but it didn't. So I updated the if-clause and not it shows me the message **difference of at least 1 hour**, because the day is next month, eben if the time is only 20mins in front. http://3v4l.org/qHjmD

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to check weather string contains that format or not, try using regular expression and then try figure out the actual date and comparing.